# Abort signal for Rat in a maze problem (SIGABRT)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was trying to solve the rat in a mze problem (https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/rat-in-a-maze-problem/1). But I am getting SIGABRT at the commented line below. I was thinking for quite a lot of time why it is happening. Can you please help? Thank you.

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    
    class Solution{
        public:
        vector<string> check(int i, int j, vector<vector<int>> &m,string str , vector<string> soln,int n)
        {
            if(i==n-1 && j==n-1){soln.push_back(str);return soln;}
            m[i][j]=0;
            
            if(i+1<=n-1 && m[i+1][j]!=0 ){str += "D"; check(i+1,j,m,str,soln,n);}
            
            else if(j+1<=n-1 && m[i][j+1]!=0 )
            {
            str += "R"; 
            check(i,j+1,m,str,soln,n);// This is causing the SIGABRT when str = "DDRDRR"
                
            }
            
            else if(i-1>=0 && m[i-1][j]!=0){str += "U"; check(i-1,j,m,str,soln,n);}
            
            else if(j-1>=0 && m[i][j-1]!=0){str += "L"; check(i,j-1,m,str,soln,n);}
            
        }
        
        vector<string> findPath(vector<vector<int>> &m, int n) {
            
            vector<string> paths;
            vector<string> soln;
            if(m[0][0]==0)return paths;
            
            paths = check(0,0,m,"",soln,n);
            
            return paths;
        }
     };
    
        
    
   int main() {
        int t;
        t=1;
        while (t--) {
            int n;
            n=4;
            vector<vector<int>> m{{1, 0, 0, 0},{1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0},{0, 1, 1, 1}};
            
            Solution obj;
            vector<string> result = obj.findPath(m, n);
            sort(result.begin(), result.end());
            if (result.size() == 0)
                cout << -1;
            else
                for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) cout << result[i] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The line that you've mentioned just calls the function; SIGABRT must stem from some other line inside that function

Answer (score 0):

There's no default case if none of the conditions match, you're simply returning void which is not a vector.

To fix it, add `return soln;` to the end of the check function.